# How to show/hide cards in with shinyjs and bslib with a D.R.Y. approach

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, bslib

Consider the following mockup shiny app. It does what I need (effectively toggling the show/hide of each card based on the checkbox, `input$checkbox`), but it's not very D.R.Y. and would be hard to scale and maintain.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(bslib)
library(shinyjs)

cards <- list(
  card(
    id = "card1",
    card_header("Card 1"),
    plotOutput("card1_plot")
  ),
  card(
    id = "card2",
    card_header("Card 2"),
    plotOutput("card2_plot")
  ),
  card(
    id = "card3",
    card_header("Card 3"),
    plotOutput("card3_plot")
  ),
  card(
    id = "card4",
    card_header("Card 4"),
    plotOutput("card4_plot")
  )
)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  useShinyjs(),
  title = "My Dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    "Controls",
    checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "Select Stuff", 
                       choices = c("card1", "card2", "card3", "card4"), 
                       selected = c("card1", "card2", "card3", "card4"))
  ),
  "Main Content Area",
  fillable = FALSE,
  cards
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$checkbox, {
    if (is.null(input$checkbox)) hide("card1"); hide("card2"); hide("card3"); hide("card4");
    if ("card1" %in% input$checkbox) show("card1") else hide("card1")
    if ("card2" %in% input$checkbox) show("card2") else hide("card2")
    if ("card3" %in% input$checkbox) show("card3") else hide("card3")
    if ("card4" %in% input$checkbox) show("card4") else hide("card4")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Quick visual:

[image]

Is there a way to abstract the multiple similar calls to `if ("cardXX" %in% input$checkbox) show("cardXX") else hide("cardXX")`? Likewise for the multiple calls to `hide("cardXX");` in the `if (is.null(input$checkbox))` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could vectorize the content of the `observeEvent`:

```
card_ids = c("card1", "card2", "card3", "card4")

observeEvent(input$checkbox, {
    lapply(card_ids, function(card) {
        toggle(id = card, condition = card %in% input$checkbox)
    })
}, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

Notice that the `toggle` call here is a short form for the `if () show () else hide ()` parts.

Concerning the `if (is.null(input$checkbox))` clause which shall hide all cards if nothing is selected I don't think that it is needed at all. If it is really needed for some reason, you could use the fact that all of your card ids start with "card" and shorten it to

```
if (is.null(input$checkbox)) hide(selector = "[id^='card']");
```

Complete example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(bslib)
library(shinyjs)

card_ids = c("card1", "card2", "card3", "card4")

cards <- list(
    card(id = "card1",
         card_header("Card 1"),
         plotOutput("card1_plot")),
    card(id = "card2",
         card_header("Card 2"),
         plotOutput("card2_plot")),
    card(id = "card3",
         card_header("Card 3"),
         plotOutput("card3_plot")),
    card(id = "card4",
         card_header("Card 4"),
         plotOutput("card4_plot"))
)

ui <- page_sidebar(
    useShinyjs(),
    title = "My Dashboard",
    sidebar = sidebar(
        "Controls",
        checkboxGroupInput(
            "checkbox",
            "Select Stuff",
            choices = card_ids,
            selected = card_ids
        )
    ),
    "Main Content Area",
    fillable = FALSE,
    cards
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$checkbox, {
        lapply(card_ids, function(card) {
            toggle(id = card, condition = card %in% input$checkbox)
        })
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```